# Нет связи с методом

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, angular, asp.net-web-api

Отправляю из клиента (Angular) данные на сервер(ASP.NET Core),
на клиенте пробежался точкой останова и все отправляется правильно, ставлю точку останова на сервере, перезапускаю все это дело, с клиента сигнал ушел, на сервере вообще тишина, причем никаких ошибок в консоли нет, будто все работает идеально, а по факту метод сервера даже не задействован...
Клиент:

```
 public save() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    this.http.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/customers/sevemessage/${this.id}`, this.message, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    });
  }
```

сервер:

```
    [HttpPut("[action]/{id}"), Route("sevemessage")]
    [HttpPut("[action]/{id}/{message}"), Route("sevemessage")]
    public IActionResult SeveMessage(int id, string message)
    {
        User currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        User recipient = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        db.Messages.Add(new Message { UserId = currentUser.Id, FriendId = recipient.Id, SentMessage = message });
        db.Messages.Add(new Message { UserId = recipient.Id, FriendId = currentUser.Id, SentMessage = message });
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```

вроде все должно работать, если не правильно что то, то хотя бы ошибку выдал, но везде тишина...

Answer (score 0):

Пока что решал вот так:

```
 public save() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/messages/sevemessage/${this.id}/${this.message}`, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    }).subscribe(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }


[HttpGet("[action]/{id}"), Route("sevemessage")]
        [HttpGet("[action]/{id}/{message}"), Route("sevemessage")]
        public void SeveMessage(int id, string message)
        {
            User currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            User recipient = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            db.Messages.Add(new Message { UserId = currentUser.Id, FriendId = recipient.Id, SentMessage = message });
            db.Messages.Add(new Message { UserId = recipient.Id, FriendId = currentUser.Id, SentMessage = message });
            db.SaveChanges();           
        }
```

Comment: функция ```err => {console.log(err)}```, которая у вас в подписке находится срабатывает тоько в случае успешного результата. Добавьте либо второй аргумент в ```.subscribe(succesResponce => {...}, err => console.log(err))```, либо ```.pipe(catchError(err => {console.log(err), return of(err)}))```

Comment: @ВладВолков Дада спасибо, все решил буквально через час после того как задал вопрос.